# R packages struggling to install

Tags: r, package

I have written code to install the R package "Matlib" on my Rstudio on my mac but I keep getting the same error message and I do not know what the message means.
[image: Image of the error message and the code I am writing to install and use the package]

Comment: Please don't post errors and code as images. It makes it harder to search in the future. Please just copy/paste the text into your post. What R version and OS version are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the new Macs don't support OpenGL, so one workaround for users of Rstudio has been suggested by rgl's author and maintainer, Duncan Murdoch. (This does require that you be prepared to install packages from source. Rstudio allows the use of `rglwidget()` for display. )

```
 install.packages("rgl", configure.args = "--disable-opengl", type = "source")
```

The problem appears to be some sort of mismatch between OpenGL and XQuartz. Details can be found by reviewing post from Duncan on the R-SIG-Mac Mailing List. There was some dialog on the mailing list a month ago now that appeared to indicate that installing the most recent version of R and rgl might have solved it, so that might be a first step.

You *should* learn to post the output of:

```
 sessionInfo()
```

... and use text, not pictures. when presenting error reports on StackOverflow.